# SQL - Linked information

Tags: sql

I have a database table, which a program is about to update.  I have taken a snapshot of the table before the program ran and a snapshot afterwards.  Here is a sample of the data:

Before update:

```
JoinReference   User
1               User 1
1               User 2
1               User 3
2               User 4
2               User 5
2               User 6
```

After update:

```
JoinReference   User
3               User 1
3               User 2
3               User 3
4               User 4
4               User 5
5               User 6
```

I am trying to find all the users that are not linked together after the update.  For example, user 1; user 2 and user 3 are linked before and after the update (even though they have a different join reference).  User 4 and five are still linked after the update.  User 6 is not linked after the update.  I am trying to return user 6 after the update.  I have tried using derived tables but it has not worked.

This is for a very large database.  The example I have given uses fields I have made up to explain the problem.  The database structure for the example would be like this:

CREATE TABLE JoinedUsers (JoinReference int, User)

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your table structure and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select     UnpairedBefore.userid
from 
           (select    main.*
           from       tableBefore main
           left join  tableBefore ref
           on         main.joinreference = ref.joinreference
           and        main.userid <> ref.userid
           where      ref.userid null) UnpairedBefore
inner join
           (select    main.*
           from       tableAfter main
           left join  tableAfter ref
           on         main.joinreference = ref.joinreference
           and        main.userid <> ref.userid
           where      ref.userid null) UnpairedAfter
on         UnpairedBefore.userid = UnpairedAfter.userid
```

**or**

```
select  [user]
from    tblBefore
where   JoinReference in 
    (
    select  JoinReference
    from    tblBefore
    group by    JoinReference
    having  COUNT(*) = 1
    )
and [user] in 
    (
    select  [user]
    from    tblAfter
    where   JoinReference in 
        (
        select  JoinReference
        from    tblAfter
        group by    JoinReference
        having  COUNT(*) = 1
        )
    )
```

Comment: This assumes that the join references are the same.  The join references could change.  Thanks.

Comment: Then I don't think your question is clear. Do you want to find those that are not linked together before AND after the update?

Comment: Yes.  Those users that are not linked before and after the update.  I have taken a copy of the table (JoinedUsers) before and a copy of the table (JoinedUsers) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You want something along the lines of

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE (row_was_updated)
   AND JoinReference IN
       (SELECT JoinReference
          FROM myTable
         GROUP BY JoinReference
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

You may or may not need `WHERE (row_was_updated)` and you'll have to fill in that logic yourself if you need it.

It's likely there would be a more efficient way of doing that, but without schema it's only possible to give general guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b1.user AS user1
     , b2.user AS user2
FROM BeforeTable AS b1                          --- user1 and
  JOIN BeforeTable AS b2                        --- user2 were linked
    ON  b1.JoinReference = b2.JoinReference     --- before the update
WHERE b1.user < b2.user
  AND NOT EXISTS                                --- and are not linked
      ( SELECT *
        FROM AfterTable AS a1                   --- after the update
          JOIN AfterTable AS a2
            ON  a1.JoinReference = a2.JoinReference 
        WHERE a1.user = b1.user
          AND a2.user = b2.user
      ) ;
```